# Goodness of fit for orthogonal least square regression

Tags: regression, matlab, goodness-of-fit, residuals

We have a set of XY coordinates which we have fitted with an orthogonal least square regression model.  We have a vector of residuals for each point and the fitted line.  How do we assess goodness of fit quantitatively?  We're currently using Matlab but are open to other approaches.